# How does one apply sepia in Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2

The old technique of setting the camera to take sepia photos doesn't appear to work when using Camera2. Is there no longer a way to apply such an effect to a photo other than to roll your own image processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE field in CaptureRequest instance via CaptureRequest.Builder method
`mBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, /*your value*/);`

http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE